# cant see my mysql data in template

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

ok so this is myproject in which i've used angularjs with php,mysql.
so this is the homepage template in which i m trying to get data from 2 tables via mysql.i m able to get the data in single html file but couldn't with the tamplates.

```
<?php
$user="root";
$pass="xxxx";
$db='neediehave';
$db = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass,$db) or die("unable to connect");
$sql="SELECT * FROM music UNION SELECT * FROM finance";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
?>

<div class="front-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="front-heading text-center">
            <h1> Do you want to learn New Skill?</h1>
            <h3> Learn new skills by searching for people having it or teach someone your skills!   </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                <div class="recent-posts text-center">
                    <h2>Recent Posts</h2>
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
<th>topic</th>
<th>information</th>
<th>Date</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="text-left">
<?php
while($music=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> ".$music['topic']."</td>";
        echo "<td> ".$music['information']."</td>";
        echo "<td> ".$music['date_time']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";


    }

?>
</tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <login-form></login-form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> topic               information                Date
>   ".$music['topic']."   ".$music['information']."   ".$music['date_time']."

this is an image..
http://postimg.org/image/4ydd3sbuf/

m getting something like this on webpage.....:(
please help me,thank you in advance..

Comment: Uh-oh... You need to understand what a Single Page Application is. Mixing php within AngularJS templates is a BAD idea.

Comment: ok ok pro...i got this..:P.........i just need to change the format into php from html..:)
sigh.....faceslap....()
btw thanks man.....

Comment: AngularJS is not JQuery. Normally, you use php/mysql to retrieve data, export it as JSON, and then use it in Angular (.html file).
If you use Angular in .php files, you will lose all the benefits of Angular, and it becomes less practical than JQuery.